how Flutter custom app setting field in android?
In IOS part, i find setting bundle in totally reach my goal. It allows me to read and config the app setting field. But i didn't find the android part. does anyone have idea about any similar thing in android?
i find the below packages is good for me at ios, but not android.
https://pub.dev/packages/settings_bundle
example show in ios
